# Ajax - Div table-row InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am using AJAX to change the innerHTML of my DIV table-row.

The problem is that when I click the button, the innerHTML only changes the first cell, and I want it to change the entire table-row.

I searched for already answered questions on here but couldn't find any that matched my issue. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

AJAX function (adapted from W3schools.com)

```
function edit_attendee(str, str2, str3) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById('three' +str).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('three' +str).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/manage/edit_attendee.phpsid=" + str2 + "&tid=" + str + "&snum=" + str3, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Table Rows

```
<div id="container1" style="padding-left:20px;paddingright:20px;width:915px;display: table;">

<?php foreach $rowing as $row{ ?>
  <div id="three<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="display: table-row;">
    <div  style="display: table-cell;">1.</div>
    <div  style="display: table-cell;">2.</div>
    <div  style="display: table-cell;">3.</div>
    <div  style="display: table-cell;">4.</div>
    <div  style="display: table-cell;"><button type="button" style="width:60px;align:center;" onclick="edit_attendee(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>,<?php echo $choice; ?>,<?php echo $snum; ?>);return false;">edit</button</div>
  </div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Is one of the closing div's inside the PHP for loop instead of outside?

Comment: yes, but I still have the same problem. Good catch though, I just fixed that.

Comment: It must have something to do with the DIV display:table-row element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `document.getElementById('three' +str).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` fill just the `'three'+str` element.
You have to assign the AJAX response to a variable and to split it.

Or, better, you can modify the edit_attendee.php script to return the whole `div id=three[id]` innerHTML with values assigned to the various columns.

Here is, more or less, what to do in the edit_attendee.php:

```
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // id comes from the query
$choice = filter_var($_GET['choice'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // choice comes from the query
$snum = filter_var($_GET['snum'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // snum comes from the query
$first = 'column 1';
$second = 'column 2';
$third = 'column 3';
$fourth = 'column 4';
$fifth = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"edit_attendee($id, $choice, $snum);return false;\" value=\"edit\" />";
echo "<div>$first</div>
<div>$second</div>
<div>$third</div>
<div>$fourth</div>
<div>$fifth</div>";
```

I suggest you to avoid to use styles directly in the HTML code: to assign classes is far better, because the code is more manageable.

For the same reason it is better to avoid too many open-close php tags between the code: a single echo printing a whole line is far easier to be debugged.

A `class="MyRow"` assigned to your "three_something" row will require this CSS:

```
.MyRow {
   display: table-row;
}
```

With this class you can assign without hassles other styles to every contained `<div>` with the CSS:

```
.MyRow div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Then the php to generate your page will be:

```
<?php
foreach ($rowing as $row) { 
echo "<div id=\"three${row['id']}\" class=\"MyRow\">
     <div>1.</div>
     <div>2.</div>
     <div>3.</div>
     <div>4.</div>
     <div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"edit_attendee(${row['id']}, $choice, $snum); return false;\" value=\"edit\" /></div>
</div>";
}
?>
```

Variables in the form `${row['id']}` allow you to write them between quotes without the need to open and close quotes, so the code is more readable. See https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex for more details.

A small digression for a quicker explanation of the {} curly brackets:

```
$glut = 'but';
echo "$glutton" // shows nothing, $glutton is not defined
echo "${glut}ton" // shows "button"
```

Back to your Javascript snippet, with these modifications the line `document.getElementById('three' +str).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` now will work because it receives the 5 inner `<DIV>` from the AJAX call.

Comment: This works with 1 problem......The edit_attendee is a form input. When I remove the <form> and </form> tags it works brilliantly. How would I go about using the form within the <DIV> ?

Comment: You don't need to use a <form>: the Ajax will keep its data directly from the <input> fields.

Comment: how does the submit button factor in?

Comment: Ajax doesn't need a submit button! Every `onclick` can activate it, both on buttons or on other elements.

Comment: Cant figure out how Ajax gets value from input without form? here is my input box from edit_attendee:                       <div ><input type="text"

name="email" id="email" value=''  /></div>                                                                And my button: <button type="button" 

onclick="save_attendee(<?php echo $tid; ?>,<?php echo $sid; 

?>,<?php echo $snum; ?>);return false;">Save</button>

Comment: Here: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "/manage/edit_attendee.php?id=" + str2 + "&tid=" + str + "&snum=" + str3, true);` - The values are passed as a GET call, just like those coming from a form, but without the need to reload the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75443/discussion-between-marco-bernardini-and-user1071915).